# What should a lecturer do when an international student plagiarises and the student claims it was unintentional?

Tags: plagiarism, international-students

A student has plagiarised her assignment. The lecturer gave all students a lecture on plagiarism at the beginning of the semester. The student maintains she was absent that day but the university does not keep records on attendance. However a copy of the lecture is on BlackBoard. Her excuse is that she didn’t realise she was plagiarising.  As she is an overseas student a fail in a unit means she risks losing her visa.

What actions should the lecturer take?

Comment: What is university policy? Can you be more specific about the nature of the plagiarism? What exactly did the student do? Quantifying the degree and extent of the plagiarism is often important.

Comment: In addition to @JeromyAnglim's questions, what policy, if any, was laid out in the course syllabus?

Comment: Academic dishonesty is about the biggest violation of scholastic principles you can make. I would argue for the full penalty, whatever is allowed by school policy. Country of origin and visa status should not make any difference. Prediction: You will have to deal with it from this same student again the future.

Comment: I thinking cheating is universally a no-no in every academic setting I can think of. So regardless of her status, discipline should be no different.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Almost every day there are around the world episodes of academic dishonesty committed by _faculties_ which are punished in much milder ways, e.g, to save a university's reputation (and we had episodes described here). Don't punish a student who committed academic dishonesty for the first time in a way that can dramatically change their life, if, as a system, you're not able to deal with dishonesty in a fair way at all levels.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: I refer you to the works of Harry G. Frankfurt.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The actual punishment is likely to be carried out by a committee, where the student will get to make an appeal and defend themselves. Depending on how rock-solid the evidence is, it might not be enough to get them to impose these "life-destroying" consequences. I don't know of a university where one professor can unilaterally impose official academic dishonesty punishments. And it sounds like you're advising that the solution to institutional dysfunction (which isn't established in this case) is to actively encourage and spread it.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins It's twenty years that I deal with international students and with cases like the above: generically referring me to a philosopher won't likely change my mind on this.

Comment: In my opinion, not being at the lecture where plagiarism is explained is no excuse to allow to plagiarize (in that case, students could just skip the first lecture so they can get away with it later?). Meaning: There have to be some rules and you even explained them. Stick to those rules yourself. Treat her like you would have treated any other student.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Procedures for evaluating and punishing academic integrity violations vary significantly between universities. At my university, the punishment is *not* carried out be a separate committee, but by the individual instructors, although there is a multilevel appeals process with its own committees. I have personally failed students for plagiarism, causing them to lose their visas. (And I slept well afterward.)

Comment: @JeffE The point, of course, is not about whether one can sleep well or not afterwards.

Comment: @MichaelC.: "I thinking cheating is universally a no-no in every academic setting I can think of." - as far as I can see, the OP hasn't yet specified in what way plagiarism has occurred. I think everyone can agree with your statement, but as soon as we'd start looking in depth at what is "cheating", we suddenly realize that people from different institutions and places may have vastly different ideas about that. I've realized that after reading here on Academia SE for a while, and coming across some (in my view) totally acceptable actions that seem to count as "cheating" in some places.

Comment: I like the idea of starting out the semester explaining clearly what is plagiarism and what isn't.  (I used to do this too.)  That would be a day to take careful attendance.  There should be a mandatory assignment based on that day's class, in which the student explains what's allowed and what's not allowed; by "mandatory," I mean that if this particular assignment is not turned in, credit for the class will not be given.  Of course, if a student is absent that day, s/he should be permitted to visit office hours to get help if need be on the plagiarism topic.

Comment: @aparente001: While in theory that sounds nice, the problem is it implies that *every course in every discipline* loses a day for the parallel "what is plagiarism" lecture. And (at least at my institution) someone also recommends a day's lecture on classroom behavior/civility contracts. And also a day on accessibility/disability/UDL awareness. And maybe an intro diagnostic test. And how to read a text in one's discipline. And someone else recommends getting into meaty material ASAP to hook interest. There just isn't time for all of it.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins - I didn't give this intro in every class I taught.  I gave it in a class that taught technical writing for mathematics undergraduates. // Does the diagnostic test take the full period?  Could you farm it out to the same office that does placement tests for incoming students?  Is it possible to combine disability awareness with another topic, and/or incorporate it into multiple classes?

Comment: @aparebte001: "Could you farm it out to the same office that does placement tests for incoming students?" - even if there is such an office/placement test (depending on the university system, there may or may not be), there is always a couple of students who got in differently - via another institution as a regular part of their studies, in a year when the office still had different procedures, via some exchange programme whose participants do nit run through that office, ... You'll always end up with a couple of students who somehow never even learned that there is such an introductory ...

Comment: ... information session on plagiarism for (in theory) everyone.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins Spell out your academic integrity (and classroom behavior, and accessibility, and other) policies in your syllabus, which is of course posted on your course web site; then you only need to cover highlights in class.  Even if you do spend significant classroom time on those policies, having an easily google-able written policy document is helpful for everyone.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Sorry, I didn't mean farm out the plagiarism explanation, I meant farm out the the diagnostic test.

Answer (score 8):

If your institution keeps a record of academic misconduct, be sure this gets into the record.  If you don't do that, you enable serial cheating.

Do not allow a "do over."  The message you send is that there's no penalty for for misconduct, even if one gets caught.  Misconduct must have some irrecoverable penalty, however small.  It need not be a grade penalty; it could be extra work, but see below about setting a penalty.

Follow University policy if there is one.  If you have the opportunity to set the penalty, and I hope you do, consider the magnitude of the offense.  A single un-cited paragraph from a work listed in a bibliography is far less egregious than a substantial part of the work copied with no attempt at attribution.

It is not your problem that the student missed the plagiarism lecture.  Do not allow the student to make it your problem.

It is not your problem that the student might lose her visa.  Do not allow the student to make it your problem.

Comment: _Misconduct must have some irrecoverable penalty, however small. It need not be a grade penalty; it could be extra work..._ - I'm not sure what you mean by "extra work" that would be an "irrecoverable penalty."  (I agree completely with all your other points.)

Comment: @Kimball Well, once the extra work has been done, the time spent doing it cannot be recovered.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft True, but I don't think most students would view this as "irrecoverable."  I would also argue that they skipped the work they were supposed to do the first time around by plagiarizing, so in a net sense they are not necessarily irrecoverably using more time.

Comment: @Kimball  Although I didn't make it clear, I had in mind *a lot* of extra work; something like writing an entirely new paper on a similar subject plus an essay about the importance of citation, with citations and a non-trivial minimum length, all to be graded and with a grade of A necessary to escape further penalty.

Answer (score 6):

Just to offer a perspective on the background of international students, especially those from underdeveloped countries from Asia, the concept of plagiarism is virtually non-existent. More precisely, students graduating from high schools in those country will probably have never heard about how plagiarism is a serious offense in developed countries like such as U.S. Like, they would not have the faintest clue about the gravity of the whole plagiarism issue.

I was one of those students and know for a fact that every single student in my high school never knew how much important citation and biography are when they were writing a paper in high school. This was literally the biggest "culture" shock I had experienced in my first year of studying in the U.S

However, I am not saying that you should not penalize the student. But if a single academic misconduct on plagiarism automatically means the student will lose his/her visa and if the student happens to be from a similar place that I was from, then maybe it would make reasonable sense to arrange something so the visa stays untouched.

Answer (score -2):

It's hard to imagine a better learning opportunity than this.  And anyway, do we want to destroy her life, or help her learn a very important lesson?

Be creative, be effective.  For example, in addition to giving her an incomplete and having her re-do the assignment, you could reduce her final grade by one letter (i.e. from B to C), and you could have her write a separate research paper describing three famous plagiarism scandals of her choice.

To quote a [classic story](http://www.uglyhedgehog.com/t-458195-1.html):

> At a certain school in [your region here] some girls were beginning to use lipstick, putting it on in the school bathroom. After they put on their lipstick, they pressed their lips on the mirror, leaving dozens of little lip prints.
>
> Every night, the maintenance man removed the prints, but the next day,
>   the girls put them right back. Finally, the principal decided that
>   something had to be done. She called all the girls into the bathroom
>   along with the maintenance man. She explained that all these lip
>   prints were causing a major problem for the custodian, who had to
>   clean the mirrors every night. This inspired yawns from all the little
>   princesses.
>
> To demonstrate how difficult it was to clean the mirrors, she asked
>   the maintenance man to show the girls how much effort was required. He
>   took out a long-handled squeegee, dipped it in the toilet, and cleaned
>   the mirror with it. Since then there have been no lip prints on the
>   mirror.
>
> There are teachers… and then there are educators.

As a graduate student instructor, I encountered these problems occasionally.  In one case, as an example, of a student who had not done his own programming, the end result was that he had to take the class again in the summer.  He learned to write simple programs, and he learned to hand in his *own* work, not someone else's.  And he got a Bachelor's degree.

Comment: I don't agree. If there are official procedures at your university follow them. Creativity has its time and place, but that's not when dealing with a serious offense. There I would argue that fairness is most important. And that means following the official procedures so everyone is treated equally.

Comment: @Roland - There are worse things, e.g. cheating in a final exam; and this mistake *has a remedy*: redo the assignment, and do an extra project.  Is our function as teachers to go around judging and punishing, or helping students understand and improve?  At least now she's paying attention.

Comment: @aparente001 The only scenario in which you are doing the judging and punishing is in the one you advise. In the official procedures there would be a committee weighing the evidence and situation to decide the appropriate course of action. You, as the professor, would be a witness; not judge, jury, or (metaphorical) executioner. Plus as a professor you have administerial duties to the department and university, as well.  You're not a pure teacher. Not to say I haven't seen many professors take things into their own hands and avoid the official procedures, but your analogy is rather mistaken.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy - Which analogy? // The student already admitted to her guilt. // How is the young woman expected to learn from the experience if you take away her visa and kick her out of the university, and the country?

Comment: If you believe the official procedures are too strict, work on changing them. If each professor can decide how to deal with such an offense, the same offense might get very different punishments just because it happened in different classes. I don't find that desirable. There needs to be at least a guideline as part of official procedures.

Comment: @Roland - I see no reason OP should not collaborate with department administrators about the problem.

Comment: Btw., there are probably millions of perfectly honest students who didn't even get the chance to visit your university. I don't agree with your "learning from the experience" argument because I don't buy the "I didn't know" excuse. They might not know the exact rules but these students know perfectly well that they are being dishonest.

Comment: @Roland - As a graduate student instructor, I had students who cheated on homework and attempted to cheat on exams, and I've had students who plagiarized.  In all cases, I worked with the department administration to address the problem.  Administration invariably sought the solution that enabled the student to *learn the lesson*.

Comment: @aparente001 So, you were not creative but followed the official procedure. That's not what you recommend in your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60565/discussion-between-aparente001-and-roland).

Comment: @aparente001 And what would other students learn from the experience? The more severe the personal consequences would be, the less severe the official ones will be? So actually, the worse my offense is for me the less I will be punished? That is not a good lesson to learn.

Comment: @skymningen - Please see my response in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60565/discussion-between-aparente001-and-roland).